# Why do I get "cannot find symbol" using scanner when compiling?

Tags: java

I'm learning java here, so as I wrote a simple program, I get an error every time I try to compile it. This is the error I get:

```
Trivia.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
ret = sc.nextline();
        ^
```

The program is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GameStart {
  public static void main(String[] args){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   String ret;
   byte qnum;
   String ans;

 String correct = "Awesomely correct!";
 String wrong = "Darn it! Almost got it!";

 System.out.println("Do you think you know your stuff?");
 ret = sc.nextline;

 if (ret.equals("yes") || ret.equals("Yes"))
 {
 System.out.println("Well, then let's test what you know! Choose a number from 1 to 5!");
qnum = sc.nextByte();
  switch (qnum)
  {
    case 1:
    System.out.println("In what year did the French Revolution start?");
    ans = sc.nextline();
      if (ans.equals("1789") || ans.equals("Seventeen eighty nine"))
      {
      System.out.println(correct);
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println(wrong);
      }
     break;

    case 2:
    System.out.println("How many protons does a sodium atom have?");
    ans = sc.nextline();
      if (ans.equals("11") || ans.equals("Eleven"))
      {
      System.out.println(correct);
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println(wrong);
      }
     break;

    case 3:
    System.out.println("What is 2^6*0.5-12?");
    ans = sc.nextline();
      if (ans.equals("20") || ans.equals("Twenty"))
      {
      System.out.println(correct);
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println(wrong);
      }
     break;

    case 4:
    System.out.println("Which is the lowest numbered element in the periodic table?");
    ans = sc.nextline();
      if (ans.equals("Hydrogen") || ans.equals("hydrogen"))
      {
      System.out.println(correct);
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println(wrong);
      }
     break;

    case 5:
    System.out.println("Which is the unit that measures Coulombs per second?");
    ans = sc.nextline();
      if (ans.equals("Ampere") || ans.equals("ampere"))
      {
      System.out.println(correct);
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println(wrong);
      }
     break;
    default:
    System.out.println("Stick to the rules! 1-5!");
  }

 }
 else
 {
 System.out.println("Not liking that attitude, I want to hear a big yes!");
 }

}
}
```

As I mentioned, I'm pretty new in Java, so you'll find more errors for sure, and my "style" may be terrible, so all suggestions are welcome! :)

Comment: `nextline` vs `nextLine`. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: not sc.nextline; its sc.nextLine();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have forgotten to add () brackets in this line

ret = sc.nextline;

also it is nextLine not nextline

change  `ret = sc.nextline;`
to

```
 ret = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Big thanks! I had already started changing the upper case issue, as I noticed it by comparing it to other code, never noticed the thing with the brackets. You deserve a beer ;)

Comment: I know, I just had a time restriction- btw, I'm getting the if statement evaluated inside each case before defining the ans variable, so it gives wrong immediatly when compiling and choosing a number, know how to fix that?

Comment: But the question is asked in each case statement, so the input would happen before the question is made

Answer (score 0):

use following

```
 ret = sc.nextLine();
```

instead of

```
 ret = sc.nextline;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be this:

> rc.next**L**ine**()**

Case is very important.

So are parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You have the [case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) wrong, and you forgot the parenthesis (and you should call [hasNextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) first) -

```
// something like this (with a ternary)
ret = (sc.hasNextLine()) ? sc.nextLine() : null;
```

or

```
if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
  ret = sc.nextLine();
} else {
  ret = null;
}
```